# Overridden Deserialize in XmlSerializer is never called

Tags: c#, extend, xmlserializer

I am slowly feeling my sanity fraying at the edges, while my mind slowly drains.

I want to extend XmlSerializer which for some reason does not support deserialization notifications.

I have the following code:

```
public class NotificationXmlSerializer : XmlSerializer
{
    public NotificationXmlSerializer(Type type)
        : base(type)
    { 
    }

    protected override object Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
    {
        var x = base.Deserialize(reader);
        var methods = x.GetType().GetMethods().Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(attr => attr is OnDeserializedAttribute));

        return x;
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
    using (MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var x = new NotificationXmlSerializer(typeof(int));
        x.Serialize(fs, 5);
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var y = x.Deserialize(fs);
    }
```

However, if I put a breakpoint in my Deserialize override, it is never hit! Even if I throw an exception in there intentionally, program function is normal, so I am sure it is never hit.

Why would they let me override an internal method Deserialize without enabling me to affect anything by it?

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards, Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as MSDN says the method is intended for internal purposes:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Second, if you look at `XmlSerializer` with Reflector, you'll discover the only place from where this method is called. The simplified control flow is:

```
public object Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
{
    …
    try
    {
        if (this.primitiveType != null)
        {
            …
            return this.DeserializePrimitive(xmlReader, events);
        }
        if ((this.tempAssembly == null) || this.typedSerializer)
        {
            XmlSerializationReader reader = …
            try
            {
                return this.Deserialize(reader);
…
```

Even though this method (`Deserialize(XmlReader, string, XmlDeserializationEvents)`) is called from all other `Deserialize` methods, it doesn't mean the control flow must end up in `Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader)`.

My advice: Get the reference source for `XmlSerializer`, study the behavior, and either solve your problem in another way or adjust the outer conditions in such a way your override is called. Personally I'd **avoid relying on overriding** the method. You will end up with **more stable behavior** and **prevent compatibility issues** with future versions of the framework.

Comment: +1 that's how far I got with reflector - the internal flow is quite complicated, I also would not advise the OP to rely on an override in this scenario

Comment: Thanks. I knew I should have read MSDN more closely, but in this case, it looked so much like a conventional way to extend the functionality - internal methods which do alot of plumbing then call Deserialize with simplified arguments. I was fooled by my assumption that it had to be what it logically looked like.

Comment: @Max If you want extensibility — **forget** about `XmlSerializer`. And use… … your own serializer. There's no other viable option as to my knowledge.

Comment: Alright.. Grumble. Seems alot of things might have been better implemented about XmlSerializer - For example, it might have been convenient if the serializer, instead of rejecting interfaces outright, saved the concrete type as an attribute at the time of serialization - should be fairly straightforward when they have already done all that other work. Anyway, thanks!